# Get multiple rows from single row based on from and to date

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 column ID , From date and To date.I need to check the date difference between from and to and add a new row based on difference.Example below.How can this be done in sql server

```
+-----+------------+------------+
| ID  |    From    |     To     |
+-----+------------+------------+
| 100 | 15/05/2016 | 17/05/2016 |
+-----+------------+------------+
```

Output that i need

```
+-----+------------+
| ID  |    Date    |
+-----+------------+
| 100 | 15/05/2016 |
| 100 | 16/05/2016 |
| 100 | 17/05/2016 |
+-----+------------+
```

Comment: So you want the average date between them ? And you mean you want to normalize your data?

Comment: Discussed 100 times. You should have a calendar table and then a join where you have between comparison in join clause.

Comment: working days or calendar?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I don't think he needs a calender table here

Comment: Actually, agreed with Giorgi.  There are a thousand good posts to explain how to do this. I'm going to vote to close your question.

Comment: Check this out about [how to post a T-SQL question](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating how many Working Days between 2 Dates - T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258767/calculating-how-many-working-days-between-2-dates-t-sql)

Answer (score 0):

There is a **[function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378593/get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-using-a-function/1378788#1378788)** here:

```
dbo.ExplodeDates(@startdate datetime, @enddate datetime)
```

Just update it to include your `ID`

```
dbo.ExplodeDates(@ID id, @startdate datetime, @enddate datetime)
```

and use it like

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.ExplodeDates(@ID id, @startdate datetime, @enddate datetime)
```