# How to count date difference excluding weekend and holidays in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to count days (business days) between two dates excluding weekend (most important) and holidays

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(end_date, start_date) from accounts
```

But, I don't know how am I supposed to do it in MySQL, I found this article [Count days between two dates, excluding weekends (MySQL only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757919/count-days-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends-mysql-only). I cannot figure out how to functional query in mysql, Can you give some information of how can achieve this with mysql query. If I am missing anything let me know.

[EDIT]

```
CREATE TABLE `candidatecase` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Unique ID',
  `CreatedBy` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `UseraccountID` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User Account ID',
  `ReportReadyID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Report Ready ID',
  `DateCreated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Date Created',
  `InitiatedDate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Date Initiated',
  `ActualCompletedDate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Date Completed Case',
  `ProjectedCompletedDate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'Date Projected Finish',
  `CheckpackagesID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Default Check Package Auto Assign Once Initiate Start',
  `Alacartepackage1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Ala carte Request #2',
  `Alacartepackage2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Ala carte Request #3',
  `OperatorID` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User Account - Operator',
  `Status` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Status',
  `caseRef` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=293 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `candidatecase`
--

INSERT INTO `candidatecase` (`ID`, `CreatedBy`, `UseraccountID`, `ReportReadyID`, `DateCreated`, `InitiatedDate`, `ActualCompletedDate`, `ProjectedCompletedDate`, `CheckpackagesID`, `Alacartepackage1`, `Alacartepackage2`, `OperatorID`, `Status`, `caseRef`) VALUES
(1, 43, 70, NULL, '2011-07-22 02:29:31', '2011-07-07 07:27:44', '2011-07-22 02:29:31', '2011-07-17 06:53:52', 11, NULL, NULL, 44, 6, ''),
(2, 43, 74, NULL, '2012-04-03 04:17:15', '2011-07-11 07:07:23', '2011-07-13 05:32:58', '2011-07-21 07:01:34', 20, 0, 0, 51, 0, ''),
(3, 43, 75, NULL, '2011-07-29 04:10:07', '2011-07-11 07:27:12', '2011-07-29 04:10:07', '2011-07-21 07:02:14', 20, NULL, NULL, 45, 6, ''),
(4, 43, 78, NULL, '2011-07-18 03:32:27', '2011-07-11 07:51:31', '2011-07-13 02:18:34', '2011-07-21 07:37:53', 20, NULL, NULL, 45, 6, ''),
(5, 43, 76, NULL, '2011-07-29 04:09:19', '2011-07-11 07:51:11', '2011-07-29 04:09:19', '2011-07-21 07:38:30', 20, NULL, NULL, 45, 6, ''),
(6, 43, 77, NULL, '2011-07-18 03:32:49', '2011-07-11 07:51:34', '2011-07-18 02:18:46', '2011-07-21 07:39:00', 20, NULL, NULL, 45, 6, ''),
(7, 43, 79, NULL, '2011-07-18 03:33:02', '2011-07-11 07:53:24', '2011-07-18 01:50:12', '2011-07-21 07:42:57', 20, NULL, NULL, 45, 6, ''),
(8, 43, 80, NULL, '2011-07-29 04:10:38', '2011-07-11 07:53:58', '2011-07-29 04:10:38', '2011-07-21 07:43:14', 20, NULL, NULL, 45, 6, ''),
(9, 43, 81, NULL, '2011-07-18 03:31:54', '2011-07-11 07:53:49', '2011-07-13 02:17:02', '2011-07-21 07:43:43', 20, NULL, NULL, 45, 6, ''),
(11, 43, 88, NULL, '2011-07-18 03:15:53', '2011-07-13 04:57:38', '2011-07-15 08:57:15', '2011-07-23 04:39:14', 12, NULL, NULL, 44, 6, ''),
(13, 43, 90, NULL, '2011-07-26 07:39:24', '2011-07-13 12:16:48', '2011-07-26 07:39:24', '2011-07-23 12:13:50', 15, NULL, NULL, 51, 6, ''),
(63, 43, 176, NULL, '2011-09-13 08:23:13', '2011-08-26 10:00:32', '2011-09-13 08:23:13', '2011-09-05 09:58:47', 41, NULL, NULL, 45, 6, ''),
(62, 43, 174, NULL, '2011-08-24 03:54:30', '2011-08-24 03:53:13', '2011-08-24 03:54:30', '2011-08-29 03:52:48', 17, NULL, NULL, 51, 6, ''),
(61, 43, 173, NULL, '2011-08-24 03:55:05', '2011-08-24 03:53:39', '2011-08-24 03:55:05', '2011-08-29 03:52:36', 17, NULL, NULL, 51, 6, ''),
(60, 43, 172, NULL, '2011-08-24 03:22:41', '2011-08-24 03:21:50', '2011-08-24 03:22:41', '2011-08-29 03:21:11', 17, NULL, NULL, 51, 6, ''),
(59, 43, 171, NULL, '2011-08-24 03:23:19', '2011-08-24 03:22:00', '2011-08-24 03:23:19', '2011-08-29 03:20:57', 17, NULL, NULL, 51, 6, '');
```

Comment: Does it have to be done all in mysql? You may need a seperate table with the holiday dates on it?  And some kind of where clause in your query.

Comment: Yes, I do have holiday table and yes it has to be done in mysql.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL function to find the number of working days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828948/mysql-function-to-find-the-number-of-working-days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You might want to try this:

1. Count the number of working days (took it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828948/mysql-function-to-find-the-number-of-working-days-between-two-dates/6762805#6762805))

   `SELECT 5 * (DATEDIFF('2012-12-31', '2012-01-01') DIV 7) + MID('0123444401233334012222340111123400012345001234550', 7 * WEEKDAY('2012-01-01') + WEEKDAY('2012-12-31') + 1, 1)`

   This gives you 261 working days for 2012.
2. Now you need to know your holidays that are not on a weekend

   `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM holidays WHERE DAYOFWEEK(holiday) < 6`

   The result of this depends on your holiday table.
3. We need to get that in one query:

   `SELECT 5 * (DATEDIFF('2012-12-31', '2012-01-01') DIV 7) + MID('0123444401233334012222340111123400012345001234550', 7 * WEEKDAY('2012-01-01') + WEEKDAY('2012-12-31') + 1, 1) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM holidays WHERE DAYOFWEEK(holiday) < 6)`

   This should be it.

Edit: **Please be aware that this only works properly if your end date is higher than your start date.**

Comment: This is working ok, but I just got negative output like -14 instead of 14.

Comment: You have to limit the subquery of your holidays to the date range you are looking for in your main query as well. (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM holidays ... WHERE date BETWEEN X AND Y`). And you should not have duplicate items in your holidays table (or change the subquery to not recognize them).

Comment: I field to succeed, let me post the script

Comment: Can you adjust your script to above query. here is my query

Comment: `SELECT 5 * (DATEDIFF(ActualCompletedDate,DateCreated ) DIV 7) + MID('0123444401233334012222340111123400012345001234550', 7 * WEEKDAY(DateCreated) + WEEKDAY(ActualCompletedDate) + 1, 1) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_holidays  WHERE DAYOFWEEK(holiday_date) < 6)  from candidatecase`

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know what you need ;-) If it is not working right, please post your holidays table and data as well, so I don't have to make up one.

Comment: I can see one of your problems is that in your data you have `created` dates that are higher that the `completed` dates, that turns your result to be negative. I honestly don't know if the query in my answer returns you correct values for this, you need to check that. If you then want positive results you might want to use MySQLs `abs()` function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10553/discussion-between-akram-and-thorsten)

Comment: `DAYOFWEEK()` returns 1 for Sunday and 7 from Saturday so I believe the condition for holidays should be `DAYOFWEEK(holiday_date) between 2 and 6`.

Comment: Not correct for same dates in 2013 and 2018. It returns 22 but should be 23 for Sat and Sun as off days

Answer (score 4):

Create a table that contains all the weekends and holidays for the next 100whatever years.

You need to be able to specify when a day is a 'holiday' given that no one knows what the holidays will be for 2052 yet, you will not be able to make an accurate function at this time anyway. just update your non-work day table each year when the holidays become known (but you will always know the weekends).

Then your query becomes:

```
SELECT DATEFIFF(end_date, start_date) - COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM nonWorkDays WHERE nonWorkDays.date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date), 0)
FROM accounts
```

If you really need to write a `DATEDIFFWITHOUTWEEKENDSORHOLIDAYS` function then just use the above and create a function (there's plenty of resources on how to make functions in each RDBMS).. just be sure to give it a better name. ^_^

One thing you will need to fix is I think there's a +1 missing somewhere in the above, for example DATEDIFF(today, today) if today is a weekend will return -1 instead of returning 0.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work.  Add all holiday dates and weekend dates to a table.

```
SELECT 
  DATEDIFF(end_date, start_date) 
FROM table
WHERE date NOT IN (SELECT date FROM holidaydatestable )
```

Comment: But, how are you going to know weekend date, this is not possible, I guess

Comment: you add the weekend dates to the holidaydatestable

Comment: how can you know all weekend for the first 10 years

Answer (score 1):

**Try This Code this will Calculate no of days Excluding Weekends**

```
 SELECT
       (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate)+1)
      -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
from test_tbl where date NOT IN (SELECT date FROM holidaydatestable )
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that will make a while cycle between the dates incrementing the number of days when it's not a saturday or sunday.

Comment: Is it possible  to achieve this without using loops, I don't have any idea about that's why I stack in this point. I was interesting if I can use just certain library to count it?