# Return value from DATE_SUB/DATE_ADD in stored function

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-function

I am trying to write a stored function that takes a string in proper ISO format (yyyy-mm-dd) and subract a certain number of weekdays from it. Based off of [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677718/how-do-you-exclude-weekends-from-a-date-sub) I have tried both the accepted answer as well as one a few answers down that does things differently, however, both of them are just saying how to write the pure sql, and don't have an example of a function.

What I currently have is this:

```
delimiter //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `WEEKDATE_SUB` (days TINYINT, date_val VARCHAR(16))
RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE SUBVAL INT;
    DECLARE dow INT;
    CASE
            WHEN dow=1 THEN SET SUBVAL = (days +(FLOOR((days-0.5)/5)+1)*2 - 1);
            WHEN dow=2 THEN SET SUBVAL = (days +(FLOOR((days-0.5)/5)+1)*2);
            WHEN dow=3 THEN SET SUBVAL = (days-1 +(FLOOR(((days-1)-0.5)/5)+1)*2 + 1);
            WHEN dow=4 THEN SET SUBVAL = (days-2 +(FLOOR(((days-2)-0.5)/5)+1)*2 + 2);
            WHEN dow=5 THEN SET SUBVAL = (days-3 +(FLOOR(((days-3)-0.5)/5)+1)*2 + 3);
            WHEN dow=6 THEN SET SUBVAL = (days-4 +(FLOOR(((days-4)-0.5)/5)+1)*2 + 4);
            WHEN dow=7 THEN SET SUBVAL = (days-5 +(FLOOR(((days-5)-0.5)/5)+1)*2 + 5);
    END CASE
    RETURN DATE_SUB(date_val, INTERVAL SUBVAL DAY);
END;//
```

When I try to add it, I get a vague error (as mysql is fond of offering):
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'RETURN DATE_SUB(date_val, INTERVAL SUBVAL DAY);
    END' at line 14

I have tried several variations on returning including trying to define a variable for Date sub and return that, but it's pretty much the same error.

Outside of a function, I know this works, so it seems like I should just be able to return that.

```
SELECT DATE_SUB("2016-01-01", INTERVAL 4 DAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs suggest you need to have [END CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html), instead of `END`

Additionally, the stored function will probably execute a little faster if you use the `CASE expr WHEN value2 THEN .... WHEN value2 THEN ... END CASE` version, since it will not have to repeat the DAYOFWEEK function calls potentially 7 times.

Comment: I gave your suggestions a shot. I am glad you caught the DAYOFWEEK thing. It's still giving the same error though.

Comment: got it. You set me on the right track. along with the END CASE, I needed a ;

Answer (score 1):

you can also use something like this

```
delimiter //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `WEEKDATE_SUB` (date_val VARCHAR(10), days TINYINT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    RETURN  date_val - INTERVAL
            FLOOR(days/5)*7 + 
            IF(DAYOFWEEK(date_val)-1 <= days - FLOOR(days/5)*5
              , (days - FLOOR(days/5)*5)+2
              , days - FLOOR(days/5)*5
           ) DAY;
END;//
```

**samples**

```
mysql> SELECT WEEKDATE_SUB('2017-02-06',1);
+------------------------------+
| WEEKDATE_SUB('2017-02-06',1) |
+------------------------------+
| 2017-02-03                   |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT WEEKDATE_SUB('2017-02-07',1);
+------------------------------+
| WEEKDATE_SUB('2017-02-07',1) |
+------------------------------+
| 2017-02-06                   |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT WEEKDATE_SUB('2017-02-07',2);
+------------------------------+
| WEEKDATE_SUB('2017-02-07',2) |
+------------------------------+
| 2017-02-03                   |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally needed to get this working. Notice, the ; and the change to how I am using the CASE statement.

```
delimiter //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `WEEKDATE_SUB` (date_val VARCHAR(10), days TINYINT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10) DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE SUBVAL INT;
    DECLARE dow INT;
    SET dow = DAYOFWEEK(date_val);
    CASE dow
            WHEN 1 THEN SET SUBVAL = (days   +(FLOOR((days-0.5)/5)+1)*2 - 1);
            WHEN 2 THEN SET SUBVAL = (days   +(FLOOR((days-0.5)/5)+1)*2);
            WHEN 3 THEN SET SUBVAL = (days-1 +(FLOOR(((days-1)-0.5)/5)+1)*2 + 1);
            WHEN 4 THEN SET SUBVAL = (days-2 +(FLOOR(((days-2)-0.5)/5)+1)*2 + 2);
            WHEN 5 THEN SET SUBVAL = (days-3 +(FLOOR(((days-3)-0.5)/5)+1)*2 + 3);
            WHEN 6 THEN SET SUBVAL = (days-4 +(FLOOR(((days-4)-0.5)/5)+1)*2 + 4);
            WHEN 7 THEN SET SUBVAL = (days-5 +(FLOOR(((days-5)-0.5)/5)+1)*2 + 5);
            ELSE SET SUBVAL = days;
    END CASE;
    RETURN DATE_SUB(date_val, INTERVAL SUBVAL DAY);
END;//
```