# Select rows from MYSQL table where dates between two columns containing weekend

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select rows from a MYSQL table where dates between two columns start_date, end_date containing weekends

I tried found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757919/count-days-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends-mysql-only) but it is not helpful

My table columns are Name start_date end_date amount

I want to print name and amount if days between start_date and end_date containing Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: Have you tried dayname() function?

Comment: Containing weekends might be difficult to achieve. May be you can try this - http://lavaneur.blogspot.in/2012/09/working-days-bw-two-days-weekends-bw.html.

Answer (score 1):

Use DAYNAME function. It gives Dayname of a particular date.

Try this,

```
select * from yourtable where 
    (DAYNAME(start_date) = 'Saturday' or DAYNAME(start_date) = 'Sunday') and
    (DAYNAME(end_date) = 'Saturday' or DAYNAME(end_date) = 'Sunday');
```

Hope it will help.

P.S. I din't run this query.

Comment: Thanks for answer but as I said in my question i want to check weekend between two days means if start_date is 2016-08-18 and end_date is 2016-08-24 then 22 and 23 is weekend which is between these dates and it should fetch this row, please suggest me how to do it

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to take two columns as start and end dates and count the number of weekend days between them. Is that correct?

This answer [How to get list of dates between two dates in mysql select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295616/how-to-get-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-mysql-select-query#answer-9296238) has some SQL for getting a list of all dates in a range.

To build on that you could use that query as an inner join, selecting only the dates you need based on your start and end columns. Then count Sundays and Saturdays using DAYNAME.

Here's an example that gets close to what you should use. **This is not exactly what you should use!** This is only built for hard coding the dates (and very close to passing them in as parameters). **You should adapt it by joining your table to it!**. I didn't write it that way because: I'm lazy and didn't want to make a table for testing and demonstrating it, and (more importantly) I wanted to help you and not just hand over a solution.

```
select count(one_date), dayname(one_date) week_day from

(select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) one_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v ) as all_days

where one_date between '2016-10-01' and '2016-11-15' -- <---- DON'T HARDCODE THESE, JOIN YOUR TABLE TO THE all_days AND FILTER THE DAYS YOU WANT THAT WAY
group by week_day
having week_day in ('Sunday', 'Saturday');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a lengthy query, may slowdown the performance. But this can give you desired output

```
SELECT x.id,x.name,x.amount FROM 
    (SELECT name,amount,DATEDIFF(end_date,start_date)+1 AS totDays,
       start_date AS day1,ADDDATE(start_date,1) AS day2,
       ADDDATE(start_date,2) AS day3,ADDDATE(start_date,3) AS day4,
       ADDDATE(start_date,4) AS day5,ADDDATE(start_date,5) AS day6,
       end_date FROM your_table)X 
     WHERE x.totDays>5 OR (WEEKDAY(x.day1)>4 AND x.day1<=x.end_date) OR 
     (WEEKDAY(x.day2)>4 AND x.day2<=x.end_date) OR 
     (WEEKDAY(x.day3)>4 AND x.day3<=x.end_date) OR 
     (WEEKDAY(x.day4)>4 AND x.day4<=x.end_date) OR 
     (WEEKDAY(x.day5)>4 AND x.day5<=x.end_date) OR 
     (WEEKDAY(x.day6)>4 AND x.day6<=x.end_date);
```

Or try this,

```
SELECT name,amount FROM your_table WHERE
    (DATEDIFF(end_date,start_date)+1) >5 OR 
    (WEEKDAY(start_date)>4 AND start_date<=end_date) OR 
    (WEEKDAY(ADDDATE(start_date,1))>4 AND ADDDATE(start_date,1)<=end_date) OR 
    (WEEKDAY(ADDDATE(start_date,2))>4 AND ADDDATE(start_date,2)<=end_date) OR 
    (WEEKDAY(ADDDATE(start_date,3))>4 AND ADDDATE(start_date,3)<=end_date) OR 
    (WEEKDAY(ADDDATE(start_date,4))>4 AND ADDDATE(start_date,4)<=end_date) OR 
    (WEEKDAY(ADDDATE(start_date,5))>4 AND ADDDATE(start_date,5)<=end_date);
```

**Notes:**

If `DATEDIFF` between `start_date` and `end_date` is greater than 5, then there will be weekends.

`ADDDATE` with `start_date` up to 5 and compare that with `end_date`and if `WEEKDAY` of the output is greater than 4, then there will be weekends.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select rows where between start and end date there is a whole weekend (Saturday and Sunday together) you may use this query:

```
select name, amount FROM your_table WHERE 
   datediff(end_date,start_date) > 6 
   or 
   (datediff(end_date,start_date)+weekday(start_date)>=6 
    and weekday(start_date)<>6);
```

Assuming start_date and end_date inclusive datediff(end_date,start_date) for the whole week is equal 6, so if there is more days than one week we can be sure there is a weekend between. When there is less days between we have to check if the number of days starting from the given start weekday will cover the weekend but we can be sure that it's not true if the start day is Sunday (starting from Sunday six days later is Saturday but these two weekend days are not one after another).

In case you want to select rows where between start and end date there is at least one weekday (Saturday or Sunday) you can use this query

```
select name, amount FROM your_table WHERE 
   datediff(end_date,start_date)+weekday(start_date)>=5;
```