# How to throw out WEEKENDS from calculation in SQL QUERY?

Tags: mysql, sql, weekend

I have SQL query which returns average utilization for some worker for previous year.

```
SELECT Name, AVG (hsum)
FROM
(
    SELECT Name,sum((number_hours)/8)*100 AS hsum
    FROM
    T1
    WHERE name='PERSON_A' and bookeddate>='2012-01-01' and booked_date<='2012-12-31'
    GROUP BY name,booked_date
) t
```

Now I want to exclude weekends for booked date for calculation? how to do it? I am using mysql
thank you

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828948/mysql-function-to-find-the-number-of-working-days-between-two-dates

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add [`DAYOFWEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) to your `WHERE` clause:

```
 AND DAYOFWEEK(booked_date) <> 1 AND DAYOFWEEK(booked_date)<>7
```

Comment: Even if this is going to work, we are always generate a table with working days into it, and in query like this you join this table. It will solve problem of US holidays and vacations etc.

Comment: @vittore he asked for "exclude weekends", not get working days. The problem can be way harder, think people that do work in the weekends, bank holidays, etc.