# How to select where there are 2 consecutives rows with a specific value using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I'm building a system that should show when the students missed two days in a row.
For example, this table contains the absences.

```
day         |   id  |   missed
----------------------------------
2016-10-6   |   1   |   true
2016-10-6   |   2   |   true
2016-10-6   |   3   |   false

2016-10-7   |   1   |   true
2016-10-7   |   2   |   false
2016-10-7   |   3   |   true

2016-10-10  |   1   |   false
2016-10-10  |   2   |   true
2016-10-10  |   3   |   true
```

> (days 2016-10-8 and 2016-10-9 are weekend)

in the case above:

- student 1 missed the days 1st and 2nd. (consecutive)
- student 2 missed the days 1st and 3rd. (nonconsecutive)
- student 3 missed the days 2nd and 3rd. (consecutive)

The query should select only student 1 and 3.

Is possible to do stuff like this just with a single SQL Query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use inner join to connect two instances of the table- one with the 'first' day, and one with the 'second' day, and then just look for rows where both are missed:

```
select a.id from yourTable as a inner join yourTable as b 
  on a.id = b.id and a.day = b.day-1 
  where a.missed = true and b.missed = true
```

**EDIT**

Now that you changed the rules... and made it date and not int in the day column, this is what I'll do:

1. Use [DAYOFWEEK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function to go to a day as a number
2. Filter out weekends
3. use modulo to get Sunday as the next day of Thursday:

   ```
   select a.id from yourTable as a inner join yourTable as b 
     on a.id = b.id and DAYOFWEEK(a.day) % 5 = DAYOFWEEK(b.day-1) % 5 
     where a.missed = true and b.missed = true
     and DAYOFWEEK(a.day) < 6 and DAYOFWEEK(b.day) < 6
   ```

Comment: you're not joining on student id

Comment: it is a little more complicated than it. I just edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

similar approach as other answers, but different syntax

```
select distinct id
from t
where
    missed=true and
    exists (
        select day
        from t as t2
        where t.id=t2.id and t.day+1=t2.day and t2.missed=true
    )
```

Comment: it is a little more complicated than it. I just edited the question.

Comment: @DanielSantos then you need to add OR condition like `( (t.day+1=t2.day) or (DAYOFWEEK(t.day) == 6 AND t.day+3=t2.day) )

Answer (score 0):

This will give you each instance of it happening. You'll get multiple hits if they have 3 or more consecutive days missed, so if that's an issue then you'll need to refine it.

```
SELECT
    T1.id,
    T1.day
FROM
    My_Table T1
INNER JOIN My_Table T2 ON
    T2.id = T1.id AND
    T2.day = T1.day + 1 AND
    T2.missed = true
WHERE
    T1.missed = true
```

Comment: it is a little more complicated than it. I just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using variables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM (
  SELECT day, id, missed,
         @rn := IF(@id = id, 
                   IF(missed = true, @rn + 1, 0),
                   IF(@id := id, 
                      IF(missed = true, 1, 0), 
                      IF(missed = true, 1, 0))) AS rn                          
  FROM mytable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @id := 0) AS var
  ORDER BY id, day) AS t
WHERE t.rn >= 2
```

The benefit of the above method is that it is scalable: it can be easily extended to check for more than 2 consecutive records of student absences.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a588/1)

Comment: it is a little more complicated than it. I just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way...

```
SELECT x.id
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN my_table y
    ON y.id = x.id 
   AND y.missed = x.missed
   AND y.day > x.day
   AND 5 * (DATEDIFF(y.day, x.day) DIV 7) + MID('0123444401233334012222340111123400001234000123440', 7 * WEEKDAY(x.day) + WEEKDAY(y.day) + 1, 1) <= 1
 WHERE x.missed = 1;
```

Comment: Can you explain the last AND ?

Comment: @DanielSantos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828948/mysql-function-to-find-the-number-of-working-days-between-two-dates