# Count number of days an employee missed work

Tags: mysql

I have a table which stores information about employees and one of those fields is Date. I want to make a query that returns a count of the number of days they have missed, not including weekends. Date format is '2018-1-1' for example, consecutive days would be '2018-1-2', '2018-1-3', and if next record is '2018-1-5', then count would increase by 1 because 2018-1-4 was a Thursday and they should have a record for that day.

Any ideas on how to best do this?

What I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM `time` where name like 'John' AND DayOfWeek(Date) not like 7 
and dayofweek(Date) not like 1  
ORDER BY `time`.`Date`  ASC
```

This is giving me all of the records for John excluding Saturdays and Sundays. What I want to do now is somehow find gaps between the dates that the records have for workdays. For example, consecutive days would be '2018-1-2', '2018-1-3', and if next record is '2018-1-5', then count would increase by 1 because 2018-1-4 was a Thursday

Comment: Please show the table schema in your question. `DESCRIBE tablename`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL function to find the number of working days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828948/mysql-function-to-find-the-number-of-working-days-between-two-dates)

Comment: What have you tried so far?????

Comment: How *best*, or just *how*?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Jim Wright is Wright by name and right by nature. But be sure to read the comments as the string provided in the accepted answer is incorrect.

Comment: I've updated the question to have more information and what I have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this possible you'll need a helper table, which can be useful also for many other purposes: a table with one column that has natural numbers starting from 0 up to some large *n*. You could create it like this:

```
create table nums (i int);
insert into nums values (0), (1), (2), (3);
insert into nums select i+4 from nums;
insert into nums select i+8 from nums;
insert into nums select i+16 from nums;
insert into nums select i+32 from nums;
insert into nums select i+64 from nums;
insert into nums select i+128 from nums;
insert into nums select i+256 from nums;
```

You can see how you double the number of records by adding a similar insert statement, but this will generate 512 records, which would be enough for your purposes.

Then you can use this query to answer your question:

```
SELECT ref_date
FROM   (
         SELECT date_add('2018-01-01', interval i day) ref_date
         FROM   nums
       ) calendar
WHERE  ref_date <= curdate()
AND    dayofweek(ref_date) not in (1, 7)
AND    ref_date NOT IN (
         SELECT Date
         FROM   `time`
         WHERE  name = 'John'
       )
```

See also [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4f7d/5)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this works beautifully. Could you explain a bit more about what the helper table is doing here, and how it could be useful for other purposes?

Comment: If you look into the helper table after you executed those inserts, you will see it has numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ..., 510, 511. It can be useful for any query where you need to select something that is *not* there. In the actual query I use these numbers to represent days to add to a starting date, but in another scenario it could be a number of hours in the day (to find missing hours)...