# How to calculate if workdays are more than 6 days from todays date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following in my select statement:

```
CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, - 5, GETDATE()) > [Date] THEN '6+' ELSE NULL END AS Test
```

This works fine, but it also includes weekends. How would I go about not counting weekends in the part that is calculating if todays date - 5 is > date? I want to use only 5 working days, not weekends.

Comment: So if 5 days back is a weekend, do you want it just to return `NULL`?

Comment: Just change the -5 to -7.  Five workdays away -- without including holidays -- is going to be exactly one week.  Voila, 7 days.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think he wants 5 calendar days and to exclude if it's a weekend

Comment: See if this helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444846/business-days-calculation

Comment: @JNK . . . The case of 5 working days is a special case.  5 working days (not counting holidays) is exactly 7 calendar days.  The method of changing the 5 to 7 only works, though, when the current date is not on the weekend.  And, this would not work for 3 or 8 days.  Just 5.

Comment: Please just build a calendar table. It will allow you to determine both weekdays/weekends *and* holidays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will exclude Saturday and Sunday from your `CASE`:

```
CASE WHEN 
    (
       (DATEADD(DAY, - 5, GETDATE()) > [Date]) 
       AND 
       (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, - 5, GETDATE())) NOT IN (7,1))
    )
    THEN '6+'  END AS Test
```

Comment: This depends on the [DATEFIRST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) setting, yes?.

Comment: Yes sorry, `DateFirst` needs to be 1

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to calculate the workdays from your [Date] to GETDATE() and apply whatever criteria to that number in your CASE expression.
To calculate the workdays, for simplicity of expressions, you can add these 2 cross-applies to your FROM clause:

```
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
    DATEDIFF(Day, 0, [Date]),
    DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GETDATE())
    )
) tmp (d1, d2)
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (
    tmp.d2 - tmp.d1 - (tmp.d2/7 - tmp.d1/7) - ((tmp.d2+1)/7 - (tmp.d1+1)/7)
    )
) diff (workdays)
```

Having done so, your case expression would look like this:

```
CASE WHEN diff.workdays > 5 THEN '6+' ELSE NULL END AS Test
```