# Exclude weekend between two timestamps in a query in Db2

Tags: db2

I have two columns with a timestamp in each

```
column_a               column_b
2021-08-03 13:22:29    2021-08-09 15:51:59
```

I want to calculate the difference in hours, but exclude the weekend (if the dates fall on or between the two timestamps).

I have tried TIMESTAMPDIFF and HOURS_BETWEEN - but these would still include the weekend.

**UPDATE:**
my solution was to ...
create a function to calculate the number of days between the two days, excluding weekends taken from here
[How to get the WORKING day diff in db2 without saturdays and sundays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135086/how-to-get-the-working-day-diff-in-db2-without-saturdays-and-sundays)

Then in my SELECT used Db2s native DATEDIFF(8,xxx,yyy) to get the total number of hours, and subtracted from this DATEDIFF, the value returned from the function * 24 (for hours)

Comment: How long is your weekend? Did you try to subtract? You can use DAYOFWEEK to find out if the given timestamp is on the weekend days.

Comment: Weekend is Saturday and Sunday. The timestamp values in column_a and column_b would be forever changing. Sometimes the timestamp might fall on on value where I could use DAYOFWEEK, sometimes the weekend might be in the middle of the column_a to column_b range, and other various combinations.

Comment: What you are saying is that it boils down to a simple IF / ELSE (=> CASE) logic you could implement. Give it a shot and report back.

Comment: What is the largest difference (could it be 30 days which would potentially include multiple weekend days?  What about national holidays which is much more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH 
  MYTAB (A, B) AS 
  (
    VALUES ('2021-08-03 13:22:29'::TIMESTAMP, '2021-08-09 15:51:59'::TIMESTAMP)
  )
, MYTAB2 (A, B) AS 
(
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(A) IN (1, 7) THEN DATE (A) + 1 DAY ELSE A END 
, CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(B) IN (1, 7) THEN B - (MIDNIGHT_SECONDS (B) + 1) SECOND ELSE B END  
FROM MYTAB
)
, R (TS) AS 
(
SELECT V.TS
FROM MYTAB2 T, TABLE (VALUES T.A, T.B) V (TS)
WHERE T.A <= T.B
  UNION ALL
SELECT DATE (R.TS) + 1 DAY 
FROM R, MYTAB2 T
WHERE DATE (R.TS) + 1 DAY < DATE (T.B)
)
SELECT
COALESCE
(
-- Seconds between start and end
  (DAYS (MAX (TS)) - DAYS (MIN (TS))) * 86400 
+ MIDNIGHT_SECONDS (MAX (TS)) - MIDNIGHT_SECONDS (MIN (TS))
-- SUM of seconds for weekend days is subtracted
- SUM (CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK (TS) IN (1, 7) THEN 86400 ELSE 0 END)
, 0
) / 3600 AS HRS  
FROM R
```

The idea is to construct the following table with Recursive Common Table expression first:

```
2021-08-03 13:22:29 --> 2021-08-04 00:00:00 (if start is a weekend)
2021-08-04 00:00:00 --> 2021-08-05 00:00:00 (if start is a weekend)
...
2021-08-08 00:00:00 --> 2021-08-07 00:00:00 (if end is a weekend)
2021-08-09 15:51:59 --> 2021-08-08 23:59:59 (if end is a weekend)
```

That is: one timestamp for each day between the start and the end timestamps. These start and end timestamps are adjusted:

- If start is a weekend - change it to the start of the next day
- If end is a weekend - change it to the end of the previous day

The final calculation is simple: we subtract sum of seconds for all weekends in the list from the difference in seconds between start and end.