# Elapsed time between 2 dates, excluding weekend in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, duration, elapsedtime, weekend

How can I calculate the time between two timestamps in MS SQL Server excluding any weekends?

For example, from 2013-05-03 17:00:00 to 2013-05-06 09:00:00 should give me 16 hours.

(Better if it's a function which I can call `fn(hours, stdt, enddt)`.)

Comment: See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331951/calculate-diffference-between-2-dates-in-sql-excluding-weekend-days?rq=1

Comment: you're going to need a calendar table to do this efficiently.