# how to calculate mysql date diff between two dates excluding Fridays and Saturdays?

Tags: mysql

how to calculate mysql date diff between two dates excluding **Fridays** and **Saturdays** as **Fridays** and **Saturdays** are off days

i've tried

`SELECT ((DATEDIFF('2022-01-02', '2021-12-30'))+1 - ((WEEK('2022-01-02') - WEEK('2021-12-30')) * 2) - (case when weekday('2022-01-02') = 5 then 1 else 0 end) - (case when weekday('2021-12-30') = 4 then 1 else 0 end)) as DifD`
but it gives wrong count (105 days) and suppose to give 2 days

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysql-function to count days between 2 dates excluding weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302181/mysql-function-to-count-days-between-2-dates-excluding-weekends)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use case expression to check if the day is `Thursday` then add `-2`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ((DATEDIFF('2014-10-25', '2014-10-15')) -
        ((WEEK('2014-10-25') - WEEK('2014-10-15')) * 2) -
        (case when weekday('2014-10-25') = 5 then 1 else 0 end) -
        (case when weekday('2014-10-15') = 4 then 1 else 0 end)) as DifD
```

// Total difference

```
SELECT ((DATEDIFF('2014-10-25', '2014-10-15'))
```

// calendar week(s) ---> not including the year

```
WEEK('2022-01-02') // = 1
WEEK('2021-12-30') // = 52
```

// get weekday, where 0 is monday and 6 is sunday

```
case when weekday('2022-01-02') = 4 // (or 5) subtract 1
```

If you want this to work on different years, like your example above u have to add 52 weeks for every year difference.
a working example would be:

```
SELECT ((DATEDIFF('2022-01-02', '2021-12-30'))+1 - ((WEEK('2022-01-02') - WEEK('2021-12-30') + 52) * 2) - (case when weekday('2022-01-02') = 5 then 1 else 0 end) - (case when weekday('2021-12-30') = 4 then 1 else 0 end)) as DifD
```

Comment: Ive tried this before but when using the dates like this SELECT ((DATEDIFF('2022-01-02', '2021-12-30')) -
        ((WEEK('2022-01-02') - WEEK('2021-12-30')) * 2) -
        (case when weekday('2022-01-02') = 5 then 1 else 0 end) -
        (case when weekday('2021-12-30') = 4 then 1 else 0 end)) as DifD ....... it gives 105 days which is not right

Comment: in this case it wont work for the dates in the same year e.g.  SELECT ((DATEDIFF('2022-01-04', '2022-01-02'))+1 - ((WEEK('2022-01-04') - WEEK('2022-01-02') + 52) * 2) - (case when weekday('2022-01-04') = 5 then 1 else 0 end) - (case when weekday('2022-01-02') = 4 then 1 else 0 end)) as DifD gives wrong days count (-101)

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you everyone for helping**, i found the answer from here [mysql-function to count days between 2 dates excluding weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302181/mysql-function-to-count-days-between-2-dates-excluding-weekends)

`CREATE FUNCTION TOTAL_WEEKDAYS(date1 DATE, date2 DATE) RETURNS INT RETURN ABS(DATEDIFF(date2, date1)) + 1 - ABS(DATEDIFF(ADDDATE(date2, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date2) DAY), ADDDATE(date1, INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(date1) DAY))) / 7 * 2 - (DAYOFWEEK(IF(date1 < date2, date1, date2)) = 6) - (DAYOFWEEK(IF(date1 > date2, date1, date2)) = 7);`

sql query for any dates e.g. :
`SELECT TOTAL_WEEKDAYS('2022-01-09', '2022-01-12') weekdays1;`