# SQL Server 2008 - Number of business days between two date columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

Any help with the syntax would be appreciated.

```
Datediff(day,dateOne, dateTwo) as TimeServed
```

How would I get the number of days between those dates excluding Saturday and Sunday? 
I do not have the ability to create functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate diffference between 2 dates in SQL, excluding weekend days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331951/calculate-diffference-between-2-dates-in-sql-excluding-weekend-days)

Comment: @Mort The possible duplicate was for Oracle and not SQL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252519/count-work-days-between-two-dates

Comment: @Mort Thanks! With that being said, do I close out the question in some regard? If so, how?

Comment: Normally, if someone had answered the question, you could mark that answer as the accepted answer. Don't think there is anything else you can do with this one though.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out below code, it might help:

```
declare @firstdate Date
declare @seconddate Date

set @firstDate = convert(date, '2019-11-01')
set @seconddate = convert(date, '2019-11-30')


select ((datediff(dd, @firstDate, @secondDate)+1) - 
    ( DateDiff(wk, @firstDate, @secondDate) * 2) - 
      case when datepart(dw, @FirstDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end -
      case when datepart(dw, @secondDate) = 7 then 1 else 0 end)
```