# How to add a given number of days to a date and exclude weekends

Tags: sql, oracle

how to add a number of days to Date field and skipping the calculation of weekends.

```
ex: if  Date  = 7/7/2021  then  Due Date = 07/21/2021`

Date = uxsubmtlDateRcvdDOP,
Number of days = 10, 
Due Date = uxsubmtlDateRcvdDOP + 10`
```

I have

```
Select uxsubmtlDateRcvdDOP + 10 as duedate
```

but that calculates the weekends as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate difference between 2 dates in SQL, excluding weekend days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331951/calculate-difference-between-2-dates-in-sql-excluding-weekend-days)

Comment: @matthias That question is full of answers about SQL Server (T-SQL) though it has no such tag. But I'll find the same about Oracle because it was asked few weeks ago

Comment: @Matthias That question is also performing the calculation in the wrong direction as it takes two dates as input and calculates the number of weekdays between them as the output; the OP wants to take one date and a number of weekdays as input and calculate a date as the output.

Comment: Are your working days Monday through Friday? (That is not the case in many countries - you should always state exactly what you mean by "work week".) Also, what if the input date is a Saturday or Sunday? I assume in such a case, adding 1 work day means returning the following Monday, but please confirm either way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT date_value,
       added_weekdays,
       weekday_date_value
       + MOD(added_weekdays, 5)        -- Number of days of part week
       + FLOOR(added_weekdays / 5) * 7 -- Number of full weeks
       + CASE TRUNC( weekday_date_value + MOD(added_weekdays, 5) )
              - TRUNC( weekday_date_value + MOD(added_weekdays, 5), 'IW' )
         WHEN 5 THEN 2
         WHEN 6 THEN 1
         ELSE 0 END                    -- Shift value if it falls on a weekend.
         AS final_value
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         date_value
         + CASE TRUNC(date_value) - TRUNC(date_value, 'IW')
           WHEN 5 THEN 2
           WHEN 6 THEN 1
           ELSE 0 END AS weekday_date_value -- Shift the start date if it is on
                                            -- a weekend. 
  FROM   table_name t
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( date_value, added_weekdays ) AS
SELECT DATE '2021-07-07', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-07-07', 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-07-07', 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-07-07', 13 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-07-10',  0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-07-10',  1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs (with the date format of `YYYY-MM-DD (DY)`):

> | DATE_VALUE | ADDED_WEEKDAYS | FINAL_VALUE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2021-07-07 (WED) | 10 | 2021-07-21 (WED) |
> | 2021-07-07 (WED) | 11 | 2021-07-22 (THU) |
> | 2021-07-07 (WED) | 12 | 2021-07-23 (FRI) |
> | 2021-07-07 (WED) | 13 | 2021-07-26 (MON) |
> | 2021-07-10 (SAT) | 0 | 2021-07-12 (MON) |
> | 2021-07-10 (SAT) | 1 | 2021-07-13 (TUE) |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=529a96b8c507d3009b45b6c6d2e55685)*

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in Oracle with a small PL/SQL function that uses [`TRUNC(<date>, 'IW')`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html#GUID-BC82227A-2698-4EC8-8C1A-ABECC64B0E79) to find the Monday of the week containing your date.

```
create or replace function plus_weekdays(d0 date, weekdays number) return date
is
  d0_Monday            date;    /* Monday <= d0 */
  weekdays_from_Monday number;  /* # of weekdays to increment from d0_Monday */
  nweeks               int;     /* # of weeks to increment from d0_Monday */
  ndays                number;  /* # of days to increment after nweeks */
begin
  d0_Monday := trunc(d0, 'iw');

  if d0 - d0_Monday >= 5 then
    -- This case means the given date is a Saturday or Sunday.
    -- We round the given date up to the next Monday and decerement the 
    -- number of weekdays that we are adding. For example:
    --   Saturday - 1 = Thursday (computed as Monday - 2)
    --   Saturday + 0 = Friday   (computed as Monday - 1)
    --   Saturday + 1 = Monday   (computed as Monday + 0)
    --   Saturday + 2 = Tuesday  (computed as Monday + 1)

    d0_Monday := d0_Monday + 7;
    weekdays_from_Monday := weekdays - 1;
  else
    weekdays_from_Monday := weekdays + (d0 - d0_Monday);
  end if;

  nweeks := floor(weekdays_from_Monday / 5);
  ndays  := (weekdays_from_Monday - nweeks * 5);

  return d0_Monday + nweeks * 7 + ndays;
end;
/
show errors;

SQL> select plus_weekdays(DATE '2020-07-07', 10) from dual;

PLUS_WEEK                                                                       
---------                                                                       
21-JUL-20
```

Comment: Please note that `remainder` is an Oracle keyword, so it would be better not to use it as a variable name in your code. Also, the OP should clarify the desired behavior if the input date is a Saturday/Sunday (presumably adding 1 work day to that should be the following Monday, in which case you would need a small modification of the code to account for that). Other than that, though, this is probably the simplest approach. +1

Comment: Fair points. I've updated the PL/SQL code based on your comments. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dateadd(mydate,,trunc(mydays/5)*7 + mod(mydays,5) + 2*trunc((weekday(mydate)+mod(mydays,5))/7))
```

The last term checks to see if you crossed a final weekend boundary.

This is a little weird if your starting date is Saturday or Sunday.  Friday + 1 day = Monday, Saturday + 1 day = Tuesday, but Sunday + 1 day is Monday.

Comment: thanks for your answer but Dateadd does not work in Oracle Sql developer and thats what threw me off.