# Number of working days between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want number of working days in between to dates. For example if we have **01-01-2012** and **20-01-2012**, i want to get the number of working days in between that two dates using T-SQL.

Comment: What days do you work?  What holidays do you have?

Comment: **Not related:** Next time, please tag it with `sql-server` not `sql` and `server`

Comment: first must know how many holidays are there then totaldays - holidays = working days..please put your table structure

Comment: I suggest you take a look at http://www.codersrevolution.com/index.cfm/2008/10/15/SQL-Server-How-Many-WorkWeek-Days-In-Date-Range or http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/07/31/week-days-between-two-dates.aspx which shows a number of different approaches to the problem.

Comment: Related/ possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252519/

Answer (score 7):

Since SQL Server has no idea what your company considers working days, the best answer to this problem is likely going to be to use a [calendar table](http://web.archive.org/web/20110314003043/http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html). Once you have a table with past and future dates, with a column like `IsWorkDay` correctly updated, the query is simple:

```
SELECT [Date] FROM dbo.Calendar 
  WHERE [Date] >= @start 
  AND [Date] <= @end
  AND IsWorkDay = 1;
```

Comment: +1 calendar table is truly the best option to deal with the ambiguity of the 'working day' concept.

Comment: The link in this answer is dead, is there an archive of it that can be linked to?

Comment: @James Sorry, updated. A group of nefarious people took over that domain and loaded it with crap.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @fromDate datetime, @toDate datetime 
SELECT @fromDate = ' 01-01-2012', @toDate = '20-01-2012'

SELECT (DATEDIFF(day, @fromDate, @toDate) + 1) 
        - (DATEDIFF(week, @fromDate, @toDate) * 2)  
        - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, @fromDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        - (CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, @toDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: This handles standard work weeks (Monday to Friday), but doesn't handle non-working days (holidays, school PA days, etc). It also assumes the language setting is `US_English` or similar. And have you tested it with different `SET DATEFIRST` settings?

Answer (score 1):

I liked Aaron Bertrand's suggestion so I wrote this code that can be added to your queries.  It creates a table variable between 2 dates that you can then use in your query by joining on the CalendarDate column (just remember to strip out any time information before joining).  This is based on the typical American work week of Monday through Friday.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @EndDate DATE

SET @StartDate = '2013-08-19'
SET @EndDate = '2013-08-26'

DECLARE @BusinessDay TABLE
(
    CalendarDate DATETIME,
    IsBusinessDay INT
)

DECLARE @Counter DATETIME = @StartDate
WHILE(@Counter <= @EndDate)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @WorkDays
    SELECT @Counter, CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @Counter) NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    SET @Counter = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Counter)
END

SELECT * FROM @BusinessDay
```

The downside is this has to be recreated for each query that needs it, so if you're doing this often, a fixed table might be a better way to go.

It can be used like this....

```
SELECT 
     BusinessDays = SUM(IsBusinessDay)
FROM
     @BusinessDay
WHERE
     CalendarDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

That will give you the count of business days between the two dates.  Like many others have said, this obviously does not take into account any holidays or my birthday.

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous code, I adapted it to exclude the last day (not asked but I needed it).

```
    select (DATEDIFF(dd,@fromDate, @toDate))    
- (DATEDIFF(ww,@fromDate, DATEADD(dd,-1,@toDate)) * 2) 
- (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @fromDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 else 0 end)
- (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @toDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 else 0 end)
```

I removed the holydays by using a table containing those dates

```
   - ( select count(distinct dcsdte) 
    from calendar_table 
    where dcsdte between @fromDate 
        and @toDate )
```