# SSRS 2008 Datediff for Working Days

Tags: ssrs-2008, datediff

I have seen this question asked a lot  and I cannot seem to find one clear answer about

*"how to calculate business days only between two dates?"*

The expression below will give me the total days but I am looking to exclude Saturday and Sunday.

```
=DateDiff("d",Parameters!STARTDATE.Value,Parameters!ENDDATE.Value)
```

I would appreciate specific help about how to accomplish this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Business Days calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444846/business-days-calculation)

Comment: If I use the query in the other post, where I do place that query in SSRS? and how do I reference it within the textbox?

Comment: Best bet would be to create a function, I should think. That's a different question to how to calculate business days though. Must admit I assumed DateDiff was the standard sql function?

Comment: Thanks - DateDiff is a standard SQL function.  However, excluding weekends from that calculation is not standard in SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL in the link ([Number of working days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081808/number-of-working-days-between-two-dates)) translated for SSRS: Hopefully this will give you a good place to start. Type this into the expression for the textbox.

```
=(DateDiff(DateInterval.day,Parameters!STARTDATE.Value,Parameters!ENDDATE.Value)+1)
-(DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,Parameters!STARTDATE.Value,Parameters!ENDDATE.Value)*2)
-(iif(Weekday(Parameters!STARTDATE.Value) = 7,1,0)
-(iif(Weekday(Parameters!ENDDATE.Value) = 6,1,0))-1)
```

Answer (score 7):

This code is not exactly correct. A year can start or end with either a Saturday or a Sunday. For example, 2011 starts on a Saturday and ends on a Saturday. January 1st & 2nd, 2011 are Saturday and Sunday respectively and Dec 31st, 2011 is also a Saturday. The above code does not account for this scenario. The code below is correct:

```
= (DateDiff(DateInterval.day,Parameters!BeginDate.Value,Parameters!EndDate.Value)+1)
- (DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,Parameters!BeginDate.Value,Parameters!EndDate.Value)*2) 
- IIF(Weekday(Parameters!BeginDate.Value,1) = 1,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Parameters!BeginDate.Value,1) = 7,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Parameters!EndDate.Value,1) = 1,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Parameters!EndDate.Value,1) = 7,1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way getting workingdays between two dates is:

```
DateDiff(DD, BeginDate, EndDate) - DateDiff(WK, Begindate, EndDate)*2
```

Comment: Not sure how/why this works but it did for me. Nice to have a simple one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me properly in all the scenarios

```
= (DateDiff(DateInterval.day,Parameters!BeginDate.Value,Parameters!EndDate.Value)+1)
- (DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear,Parameters!BeginDate.Value,Parameters!EndDate.Value)*2)
- IIF(Weekday(Parameters!BeginDate.Value,1) = 1,1,0)
- IIF(Weekday(Parameters!EndDate.Value,1) = 7,1,0)
```