# SSRS to get Field Based on Expression, based on working days

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I want to display the header of my ssrs report in the format as in excel...
Ignore the details in the table :) I am trying to display the DAY1, Day2 header in my SSRS as shows in excel.
Logic Says (if today is working day then until the last working day +1 it should display Day1 else, minus 1..basically Business days is calculated.
Hope the picture is clear below.

[image]

Tried doing this in SSRS.
enter image description here

[image]

[image]

I Want to last image to display the same as the first one, that is taken through Excel.

Please help.

Comment: You're going to need another level of **COLUMN Grouping** that's based on a formula to calculate business days. That will group by the Day# as in the Excel example.  
Here's a formula: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706897/ssrs-2008-datediff-for-working-days

Comment: This is not solving my purpose..It give the difference between the dates, whereas i have condition for business days and holidays.