# Is there an SSRS expression for calculating difference between two days excluding weekends, Saturday and Sunday?

Tags: c#, date, reporting-services, expression, weekend

I'm able to calculate date difference between two dates, however, its include all weekends. But I need difference excluding weekends like Saturday and Sunday. I am using below expression:

=DateDiff("d", Fields!StartDate.Value,Fields!EndDate.Value)

Comment: Try looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706897/ssrs-2008-datediff-for-working-days) post on the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in SSRS, go to the report code window and add the below

```
Function getWorkingDaysCount(ByVal tFrom As Date, ByVal tTo As Date) As Integer

    Dim tCount As Integer
    Dim tProcessDate As Date = tFrom
    For x as Integer= 1 To DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, tFrom, tTo) + 1
      If Not (tProcessDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or tProcessDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday) Then
        tCount = tCount + 1
      End If
      tProcessDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, tProcessDate)
    Next
    Return tCount

End Function
```

In the textbox where you need to display the value, add the below expression

```
=Code.getWorkingDaysCount(parameters!StartDate.Value,parameters!EndDate.Value)
```

Hope this helps you.