# How to calculate days count between 2 date in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm creating a system to calculate user working days.

Suppose user 1 has been at work from `2020-02-01` to `2020-02-20`.

And user 2 has been at work from `2020-02-10` to `2020-02-15`

**In Sql Server**

I have something similar in the table below

[image]

Now i want to calculte count of user working days between 2 date

**For Example**

```
Select Sum(DateDiff(Day,StartDate,EndDate)) From Table1 Where StartDate >= '2020-02-08' And EndDate <= '2020-02-12'
```

Above query returns 0 . But in this date user 1 has 5 working days and user 2 has 3 working days.

How can i calculate this?

I want a similar answer below:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL SERVER: Get total days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068017/sql-server-get-total-days-between-two-dates)

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749877/t-sql-get-number-of-working-days-between-2-dates

Comment: Define "working days" please. Monday to Friday? something else? Anyway, this has definitely been asked and answered many times either way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [T-SQL get number of working days between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749877/t-sql-get-number-of-working-days-between-2-dates)

Comment: @underscore_d No All days that user has been in `startdate` and `enddate`. Holidays are not important here

Comment: Explain your logic. Both users should have the same working day values since their start and end dates OVERLAP the entire date period (Feb 8 ~ Feb 12) of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datediff()` -- after testing for the limits of the period that you want:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(day,
                case when startdate < '2020-02-08' then '2020-02-08' else startdate end),
                case when enddate > '2020-02-12' then '2020-02-12' else startdate end)
               ) + 1
from t;
```

The `+ 1` is because you are including the last day in the calculation.

Note:  This only works correctly when there is an overlap.  You want a filter:

```
(enddate >= '2020-02-08' or startdate <= '2020-02-12')
```

Based on the question, I'm not sure if this should be in a `WHERE` clause or a `CASE` expression.  That is, do you want to filter out non-overlaps or do you want them to appear as `0`/`NULL`?

Comment: I think your answer is correct, but why is the answer a negative number?

Comment: @topcool Don't think. Run the code yourself and test/verify it. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c57c92f26be70bd7a1037e8fd07bfeb4). Then mark it as the answer if it works as you desire.

Comment: @SMor I know this. I'm testing code. If I'm sure its correct mark it as the correct answer

Comment: @topcool . . . There was a typo on the `enddate` logic.

Comment: yes, i think this question is false in some condition!