# Subtract date from day field

Tags: sql-server, date

**Original Question**

I need to write a Microsoft SQL statement where I subtract a date from number of days from another table. So, essentially, the table example is below:

```
Table 1 (date)           Table 2 (number of days)
2013-05-08 23:59:13.000     7
2013-05-08 23:59:16.000     7
2013-05-08 23:59:06.000     7
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Updated Question**

The only two item I have to work with is the following information:

[image]

I need to know how long an invoice has been in the invoice queue. TimeoutDate is when the invoice will timeout of the queue, and TimeOutDays is the length of days this queue is given before it times out, but it's business days, so excluding weekends.

So, if you calculate based on this information, the invoice has been in the queue for **8 business days** <-- this is the answer I need to get from the query.

*Extra Information*

The invoice entered into the system 04/30/2013, but since the webapp does not count the day the invoice entered the system, the time-out counter starts the day after, which is 05/1/2013. Hope this explains a little clearer!

I have a quick query, but that's not going to help, since it doesn't show what I need, but in effect below is the results of what I need:

[image]

Comment: You can use DATEADD Function, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx. However, how are you going to join those 2 tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, -(t2.days), t1.datefield) new_date
  FROM table1 t1 JOIN
       table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Output:

```
|                   NEW_DATE |
------------------------------
| May, 01 2013 23:59:13+0000 |
| May, 01 2013 23:59:16+0000 |
| May, 01 2013 23:59:06+0000 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5e7b/5)**

**UPDATE:** A solution to the completely changed question

```
SELECT timeoutdate,
       timeoutdays,
       timeoutdays
       -((DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), timeoutdate) + 1)
       -(DATEDIFF(wk, GETDATE(), timeoutdate) * 2)
       -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) daysinqueue
FROM table1
```

Output:

```
|             TIMEOUTDATE | TIMEOUTDAYS | DAYSINQUEUE |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 2013-05-14 23:59:13.000 |          10 |           9 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ea8d/2)**

*Thanks @CMS for a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/252533/1920232) for getting number of working days between two dates*

Comment: Thank you both, I'll try, and let you know how it went!

Comment: @Anon Did it help? Do you need more help on your question?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't checked it out yet..but going to check it out soon. Will let you know, thanks for the follow-up

Comment: Yes peterm, I need more help! I just put my question up..and it's little more difficult.

Comment: @Anon First of all, you better post your additional information in your original question. Just use edit link for that. And delete posted answer. Secondly your explanation is very confusing and doesn't correlate to the sample data you provided. Can you post source sample data and desired result **based on that data** in a tabular form?

Comment: OMGosh! Thanks it works perfectly..and very efficiently! I defintaely wouldn't have got it working without you. Thanks PeterM!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
Select DATEADD(month, -(Table2.day) , Table1.date) 
FROM Table1 Inner Join Table2
ON Table1.Col=Table2.Col
```

Of-course you can modified the join as per your structure.