# Calculations excluding weekends

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datediff, weekend

I am trying to make a holiday booking application and it runs of a JQuery UI calendar. the star and end date they select are passed to SQL where it puts the holiday into the requested table. the only problem is if i put a start and an end date in, it doesn't take into account the weekends. each user of the system has 21 days allowance off per calendar year and it deducts the weekends of this also. here is the current code.

```
SET @DateDiff = (DATEDIFF(Day,@StartDate,@EndDate) +1)
```

Above is the date-diff statement and below is the insertion code

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Holidays(EmployeeID, StartDate, EndDate, Duration,Status)
    VALUES(@EmployeeID, @StartDate, @EndDate, @DateDiff,'PE')

    UPDATE Employees
    SET AnnualDaysHolidayAllowance = AnnualDaysHolidayAllowance - @DateDiff
    WHERE ID = @EmployeeID
    SELECT 'successful' AS result
END
```

There is more code for the business checks and rules but this is the only part i need to try and fix. i am relatively new to coding so if possible please leave an explanation to help me understand the fix, thanks.

Comment: What RDBS do you use?

Comment: Do you *only* need to account for weekends, or are there "standard" holidays in your area that should also be taken into account? If the latter, it's usually a pointer towards creating a calendar table that can contain information on weekends, standard holidays, and even other special events specific to your organization.

Comment: RDBS smells like MS-SQL to me...

Comment: Added sql-server tag because the syntax sure looks like SQL Server.

Comment: Have a look at this article - it should help...

[Stack Overflow article][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252519/count-work-days-between-two-dates

Comment: @MartinMilan it is MS-SQL

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i only need to account for weekend the business rules leading up to this have a json file attached to retrieved standard holidays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution it was on the link posted.
source: [Count work days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252519/count-work-days-between-two-dates)
The answer (not my own work)

```
    SET @DateDiff = (SELECT
                    (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
                    -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
                    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
```