# count week days in sql by datediff

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a way to calculate the days between two dates, but on weekdays.  Here is the formula, but it counts weekend days.

```
DATEDIFF(DAY,STARTDATE,ENDDATE) 
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,'2015/06/01' , '2015/06/30')
```

Result of above query of datediff is 29 days which are weekend days. but i need week days that should be 21 by removing Saturday and Sunday(8 days). 
Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of SQL server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in the WHERE clause

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,'2015/06/01' , '2015/06/30')
FROM yourtable
WHERE DATENAME(dw, StartDate) != 'Saturday' 
AND DATENAME(dw, StartDate) != 'Sunday'
```

Or all in a SELECT statement

```
SELECT (DATEDIFF(dd, StartDate, EndDate) + 1)-(DATEDIFF(wk, StartDate, EndDate) * 2)-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Answer (score 1):

This returns `22`:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATE = '20150601'
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATE = '20150630'

SELECT
   (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate))
  -(DATEDIFF(WEEK, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Read this [article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/calculatingworkdays/1660/) by Jeff Moden for more information.

Explanation:

First, `(DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate))` will return the difference in number of days. In this case, it'll be `29`. Now, depending on your interpretation of whole days, you may want to add `1 day` to its result.

Next,`(DATEDIFF(WEEK, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)`:

To quote the article:

> `DATEDIFF` for the `WEEK` datepart doesn't actually calculate weeks, it
>   calculates the number of times a date range contains dates that
>   represent pairs of Saturdays and Sundays. To think of it in more
>   simple terms, it only counts WHOLE WEEKENDS!

So, to exclude the weekends, you must subtract twice the result of this from the first `DATEDIFF`. Which now will be: `29 - (2 *4) = 21`.

Finally, this:

```
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

removes the partial weeks, which only happens when then `@StartDate` occurs on a Sunday and the `@EndDate` occurs on a Saturday.

Comment: At least edit the answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252519/count-work-days-between-two-dates before you just copy and paste it

Comment: @Matt, I didn't copy it from that answer. See my referenced article. Maybe we had the same reference. Note that I removed the `+1` from the first `DATEDIFF`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try recursive cte:

```
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   CAST('2015/06/01' AS DATE) AS dt ,
                        DATEPART(WEEKDAY, '2015/06/01') AS wd
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   DATEADD(d, 1, dt) AS dt ,
                        DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(d, 1, dt))
               FROM     cte
               WHERE    dt < '2015/06/30'
             )
    SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   wd NOT IN ( 7, 1 )
```

Result is 22.
You better add some useful calendar table that every database should have. Fill it with some big range and then use it to calculate business days.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple stored procedure - don't know if a SP is what you need but i think you can easily convert it to a function , TVF, whatever:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[BusinessdaysBetween](@DateFrom DATE, @DateTo DATE, @days INT OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @datefirst INT = @@DATEFIRST
    SET DATEFIRST 1  --so week starts on monday

    SET @days = 0


    IF @DateFrom > @DateTo
        RETURN NULL

    IF @DateFrom = @DateTo
        RETURN @days

    WHILE @DateFrom <= @DateTo
    BEGIN
        IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@DateFrom) NOT IN (6,7) --Saturday or Sunday
        BEGIN
            SET @days = @days + 1
        END

        SET @DateFrom = DATEADD(DAY,1,@DateFrom)
    END

    SET DATEFIRST @datefirst --restore original setup
END
GO
```

in my example i call i it like this:

```
DECLARE @days INT = 0
DECLARE @datefrom DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @dateto DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY,25,GETDATE())

EXEC dbo.BusinessdaysBetween @datefrom, @dateto, @days OUTPUT 

SELECT @days
```

Comment: Since you cannot use `SET` commands i a Function you will need to check `@@DATEFIRST` inside, but i think there are only 2 cases which are use (on the databases an servers i have seen so far). `@@DATEFIRST = 1` (week starts monday) or `@@DATEFIRST = 7` (week starts sunday). Just check the value of `@@DATEFIRST` in your database...

Comment: You might want to use `DATENAME`, since it's not dependent on `@@DATEFIRST`.

Comment: thanks @wewesthemenace , but i thnk DATENAME depends on language !?

Comment: Now that I'm unsure, =)

Comment: Apparently, `DATENAME` depends on language. Try `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH`.