# How to exclude dates from a table when searching between two dates?

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I have created a query where it can search between two dates to calculate working days excluding bank holidays.

I have created a table with dates inside of bank holidays

How can i create a query where when searching between the two dates, it excludes the dates within the table?

Here is what i have so far...

```
 DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
   DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
-- Calculate the calendar working days below INCLUDING BH
--YEAR/MONTH/DATE
    SET @StartDate = '2016/09/01'
    SET @EndDate = '2016/09/30'
    SELECT
       (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
      -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
       DECLARE @TotalDays INT, @WorkDays INT
       SET @TotalDays = (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) +1)
       print @TotalDays
```

Comment: This isn't MySQL code. It might be SQL Server code. Would you kindly [edit] your tags to reflect the brand and model of table server you are actually using.

Comment: I guess you are substracting to many days already: "-(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)" and the Saturday / Sunday handling are identical, aren't they? And according to the holidays: I would suggest loading a table / temp table / table variable with the holidays beforehand and then select your dates except the holidays. Furthermore: it might be worth to try creating a date table wich covers all dates in the required daterange and then exclude specific values. This is what is done with SimDate in BI scenarios.

Comment: So can you show me a solution? I have entered the bank holiday dates into a table called bankholidays with a colun name of Bank_Holidays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate between two dates by manipulating this

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(500), 
@Region VARCHAR(100) = 'COLUMN2', --It can be Column1, Column2.....
@StartDate DATETIME = '2016-04-10',
@EndDate DATETIME = '2016-04-15'

SET @sql = '
    SELECT
    COUNT(' + @Region + ')
    FROM  bankholidays
    WHERE ' + @Region + ' BETWEEN ''' + CAST(@StartDate AS VARCHAR) + ''' AND ''' + CAST(@EndDate AS VARCHAR) + ''''

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're already using [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252519/count-work-days-between-two-dates) to get the working days (i.e. excluding weekends) between two dates.

*NB: This solution assumes that the session's language is English, and that Saturday and Sunday are considered non-working days; these assumptions may not be true for all cultures.*

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240772/how-to-use-a-case-statement-within-a-select-count-statement) it seems you're already on the right track for excluding bank holidays.  i.e.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2016-09-01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2016-09-30'

DECLARE @TotalDays INT, @WorkDays INT

SELECT
    @TotalDays = (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) +1)
    , @WorkDays = 
       (DATEDIFF(dd, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)  --get the number of working days between 2 dates (including the date itself)
      -(DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, @EndDate) * 2)  --get the number of weekend days (i.e. 2 x number of weeks)
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) --\_then take into account if the current date fell over a weekend
      -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) --/
      - coalesce(
      (
          select count(1) 
          from BankHolidays 
          where HolidayDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
      )
      ,0) --and remove any bank holidays which fall during this period

print @TotalDays
print @WorkDays
```

Note also that this assumes that all of the bank holidays in your table are against weekdays; not weekends (i.e. otherwise those days would be included twice).

- In the UK if a bank holiday falls on a weekend (e.g. Christmas this year is on a Sunday), that bank holiday is offset to the next working day (also taking into any other bank holidays; i.e. boxing day on 26th December is a bank holiday in the UK, so the Christmas bank holiday falls on 27th (or falls on 26th and Boxing day's offset to 27th, depending how you prefer to imagine it).
- However other cultures may behave differently.  Also some people are expected to work weekends, so should the holiday normally fall on the weekend they may still get that as a holiday and not have the offset bank holiday instead; just to add more confusion).