# SUMIF greater than and Workday column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I'm trying to convert an Excel table into SQL and I'm having difficulty coming up with the last 2 columns.  Below, find my Excel table that is fully functional (in green) and a table for the code that I have in SQL so far (in yellow).  I need help replicating columns C and D, I pasted the Excel formula I'm using so you can understand what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Here's the code that I have so far:

```
WITH
    cte_DistinctScheduling AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            s.JobNo
        FROM 
            dbo.Scheduling s
        WHERE 
        s.WorkCntr = 'Framing')
SELECT 
  o.OrderNo,
  o.Priority AS [P],
  SUM(r.TotEstHrs)/ROUND((8*w.CapacityFactor*(w.UtilizationPct/100)),2) AS 
  [Work Days Left],
  Cast(GetDate()+ROUND(SUM(r.TotEstHrs)/ROUND((8*w.CapacityFactor*
(w.UtilizationPct/100)),2),3) AS DATE) AS DueDate
FROM OrderDet o JOIN cte_DistinctScheduling ds ON o.JobNo = ds.JobNo
  JOIN OrderRouting r ON o.JobNo = r.JobNo
  JOIN WorkCntr w ON r.WorkCntr = w.ShortName
WHERE r.WorkCntr = 'Framing'
  AND o.OrderNo NOT IN ('44444', '77777')
GROUP BY o.OrderNo, o.Priority, ROUND((8*w.CapacityFactor*
(w.UtilizationPct/100)),2)
ORDER BY o.Priority DESC;
```

My work days left column in SQL gets the right amount for that particular row, but I need it to sum itself and everything with a P value above it and then add that to today's date, while taking workdays into account.  I don't see a Workday function in SQL from what I've been reading, so I'm wondering what are some creative solutions?  Could perhaps a CASE statement be the answer to both of my questions?  Thanks in advance

Comment: There is not enough information here. You need to provide some sample data, preferably using SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while to understand how is the Excel helpful, and I'm still having a hard time absorbing the rest, can't tell if it's a me thing or a you thing, in any case...

First, I've mocked up something to test `SUM` per your rationale, the idea is doing a self-`JOIN` and summing everything from that `JOIN` side, relying on the fact that `NULL`s will come up for anything that shouldn't be summed:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(P int, [Value] int)
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 1, 5
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 2, 6
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 3, 2
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 4, 4
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 5, 9

SELECT T1.P, [SUM] = SUM(ISNULL(T2.[Value], 0))
FROM @TABLE AS T1
LEFT JOIN @TABLE AS T2 ON T2.P <= T1.P
GROUP BY T1.P
ORDER BY P DESC
```

Second, workdays is a topic that comes up regularly. In case you didn't, consider reading a little about it from previous questions, I even [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45078810/t-sql-calculate-the-number-of-hours-between-dates-but-ignore-the-hours-from-we/) on one question last week, and the thread as a whole had several references.

Thirdly, we could use [table definitions and sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) loaded on SQL itself, something like I did above.

Lastly, could you please check result of `UtilizationPct / 100`? If that's an integer-like data type, you're probably getting a bad result on it.