# Count days between two dates excluding Sunday and Indian festival holidays

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using this query to count days.

I have tried:

```
select DATEDIFF(day, @startdate, @enddate)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count work days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252519/count-work-days-between-two-dates)

Comment: You should have a calendar table. See https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/    - By: Aaron Bertrand