# How to get the number of weekend days in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to count the number of saturdays and sundays in a certain year. Is there any way that I can do that in sql?

Comment: What does this have to do with sql?

Answer (score 0):

As alternative solution you could have a look at the answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252519/count-work-days-between-two-dates) right here.
It shows how to calculate the weekdays between to dates and can be easily adjusted to calculate Saturdays/Sundays.