# How to only add business days to a date in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dateadd

For a given date I want to add business days to it. For example, if today is 10-17-2022 and I have a field that is 8 business days. How can I add 8 business days to 10-17-2022 which would be 10-27-2022.

**Current Data:**

| BUSINESS_DAYS | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 10-11-2022 |
| 10 | 10-13-2022 |
| 9 | 10-12-2022 |

**Desired Output Data**

| BUSINESS_DAYS | Date | FINAL_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 10-11-2022 | 10-21-2022 |
| 10 | 10-13-2022 | 10-27-2022 |
| 9 | 10-12-2022 | 10-25-2022 |

As you can see we are skipping all weekends. We can ignore holidays for now.

**Update**:
Using
The suggest logic I got the following answer. I changed the names up.
I used:

```
   DATE_ADD(A.PO_SENT_DATE  , INTERVAL
  (CAST(PREDICTED_LEAD_TIME AS INT64) 
  +  (date_diff(A.PO_SENT_DATE  , DATE_ADD(A.PO_SENT_DATE  , INTERVAL CAST(PREDICTED_LEAD_TIME AS INT64) DAY), week)* 2)) 
  DAY) as FINAL_DATE
```

[image]

Update2: Using the following:

```
  DATE_ADD(`Date`, INTERVAL
  (BUSINESS_DAYS 
  +  (date_diff( DATE_ADD(`Date`, INTERVAL BUSINESS_DAYS DAY),`Date`, week) * 2)) 
  DAY) as FINAL_DATE
```

There are instances where the result falls on the weekend. See screenshot below. 10-22-2022 falls on a Saturday.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DATE\_DIFF but only counting business days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55956297/date-diff-but-only-counting-business-days)

Comment: I want to add business days to the date field, do not need the difference in business days

Comment: for the first line it should be the 20th as end date

Comment: Depends where you start counting from

Comment: you can use the solution from Lamu, to calculate the number of dates you actually have to add

Comment: Could someone apply that logic to this question? I am not full understanding how to apply that logic to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below simple solution

```
select *,
  ( select day
    from unnest(generate_date_array(date, date + (div(business_days, 5) + 1) * 7)) day
    where not extract(dayofweek from day) in (1, 7)
    qualify row_number() over(order by day) = business_days + 1
  ) final_date 
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question

```
with your_table as (
  select 8 business_days, date '2022-10-11' date union all
  select 10, '2022-10-13' union all
  select 9, '2022-10-12' 
)
```

output is

[image]

Comment: I dont need to do any date_adds? Sorry but I am not understanding how to apply this solution

Comment: lol. you have exact that tag in your question - `dateadd` . as of how to apply? just run it against your real table (replace `your_table` with actual reference

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @mikhailberlyant is really really cool, and very innovative. However if you have a lot of rows in your table and value of "business_days" column varies a lot, query will be less efficient especially for larger "business_days" values as implementation needs to generate entire range of array for each row, unnest it, and then do manipulation in that array.

This might help you do calculation without any array business:

```
select day, add_days as add_business_days, 
DATE_ADD(day, INTERVAL cast(add_days +2*ceil((add_days -(5-(
  (case when EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM day) = 7 then 1 else EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM day) end)
  -1)))/5)+(case when EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM day) = 7 then 1 else 0 end) as int64) DAY) as final_day
  from 
  (select parse_date('%Y-%m-%d', "2022-10-11") as day, 8 as add_days)
```