# If today is friday then extract data 7 to 9 days from today, if not 7 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If today is Friday, I would like to get data 7 to 9 days from now, if not 7 days. I am using SQL Server.

Before:

| id | class | startdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | English | 2020-12-21 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | English | 2020-12-22 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | Math | 2020-12-21 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | English | 2020-12-27 00:00:00.000 |
| 5 | Math | 2020-12-27 00:00:00.000 |

If today is 14/12/2020 - Monday, it will produce the result below:

| id | class | startdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | English | 2020-12-21 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | Math | 2020-12-21 00:00:00.000 |

I tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
select id, class, startdate
from class
where case datepart(w, GETDATE())
    when 6 then startdate between DateAdd(dd,+9,GETDATE() ) and DateAdd(dd,+10,GETDATE()))
    else startdate between DateAdd(dd,+7,GETDATE() ) and DateAdd(dd,+8,GETDATE()))
end
order by startdate
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count work days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252519/count-work-days-between-two-dates)  Standard approach is to create a 'working days' or 'holidays' table (or a 'dates' table with a working day/non-working day flag) this allows you to extend your solution to public holidays etc.

Comment: Aside: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a `CASE` expression like this in SQL Server.
Try this instead:

```
select id, class, startdate
from class
cross apply 
(
   select case datepart(dw, GETDATE())
           when 6 then 9
           else 7
         end
) t(days)
where startdate between dateadd(dd, t.days ,GETDATE()) an dateadd(dd,t.days+1,GETDATE())
order by startdate
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7d2094/3)

To answer to your comment:

```
select id, class, startdate
from class
cross apply 
(
select 
  case datepart(dw, GETDATE())
           when 6 then 9
           else 7
         end,
  case datepart(dw, GETDATE())
           when 6 then 11
           else 8
         end  
) t(days1, days2)
where startdate between dateadd(dd, t.days1 ,GETDATE()) and dateadd(dd,t.days2,GETDATE())
order by startdate
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping out. How about if Friday, it will extract out 7th to 9th day of data -- I missed out this condition.

Answer (score 2):

`OR` usually prevents index usage anyway, so you can do:

```
where datediff(day, getdate(), startdate)
          between 7 and
                  (case when datepart(weekday, GETDATE()) = 6 then 9 else 7 end)
```

If you are interested in performance, then use two separate queries:

```
select id, class, startdate
from class
where datepart(weekday, getdate()) = 6 and
      startdate >= dateadd(day, 7, convert(date, getdate())) and
      startdate <= dateadd(day, 9, convert(date, getdate())) 
union all
select id, class, startdate
from class
where datepart(weekday, getdate()) <> 6 and
      startdate = dateadd(day, 7, convert(date, getdate()));
```

SQL Server should find this easier to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

If you have datetime with actual hh:mi:ss in it - just change it to date and and it would be much easier

```
select id, 
       class, 
       startdate
from class
where (datepart(w, GETDATE()) = 6 and
    startdate = CAST(DateAdd(dd,+9,GETDATE()) as date) 
) 
    or (datepart(w, GETDATE()) != 6 and
    startdate = CAST(DateAdd(dd,+7,GETDATE()) as date) 
       )
order by startdate
```

If it is not an option try this:

```
select id, 
       class, 
       startdate
from class
where (datepart(w, GETDATE()) = 6 and
    startdate between DateAdd(dd,+9,CAST(GETDATE() as date)) 
                  and DATEADD(second,-1,datediff(dd,0,DateAdd(dd,+9,CAST(GETDATE() as date)))+1)
    ) 
    or (datepart(w, GETDATE()) != 6 and
    startdate between DateAdd(dd,+7,CAST(GETDATE() as date)) 
                   -- to get YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00
                  and DATEADD(second,-1,datediff(dd,0,DateAdd(dd,+7,CAST(GETDATE() as date)))+1)
                  -- to get YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59
       )
order by startdate
```

Answer (score 0):

This has probably been made more complicated than it should.
Create two parameters @start and @end
If today is Friday set parameters as appropriate else if it is not set as needed.
Use parameters in your query