# Computing number of business days between start/end columns

Tags: apache-spark, date, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two Dataframes

- facts:

  - columns: `data`, `start_date` and `end_date`
- holidays:

  - column: `holiday_date`

What I want is a way to produce another Dataframe that has columns:
`data`, `start_date`, `end_date` and `num_holidays`

Where `num_holidays` is computed as: Number of days between start and end that are not weekends or holidays (as in the `holidays` table).

The [solution is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20149314/496289) if we wanted to do this in PL/SQL. Crux is this part of code:

```sql
    --Calculate and return the number of workdays using the input parameters.
    --This is the meat of the function.
    --This is really just one formula with a couple of parts that are listed on separate lines for documentation purposes.
    RETURN (
        SELECT
        --Start with total number of days including weekends
        (DATEDIFF(dd,@StartDate, @EndDate)+1)
        --Subtact 2 days for each full weekend
        -(DATEDIFF(wk,@StartDate, @EndDate)*2)
        --If StartDate is a Sunday, Subtract 1
        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @StartDate) = 'Sunday'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END)
        --If EndDate is a Saturday, Subtract 1
        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @EndDate) = 'Saturday'
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END)
        --Subtract all holidays
        -(Select Count(*) from [dbo].[tblHolidays]
          where  [HolDate] between @StartDate and @EndDate )
        )
    END
```

I'm new to pyspark and was wondering what's the efficient way to do this? I can post the udf I'm writing if it helps though I'm going slow because I feel it's the wrong thing to do:

- Is there a better way than creating a UDF that reads the `holidays` table in a Dataframe and joins with it to count the holidays? Can I even join inside a udf?
- Is there a way to write a `pandas_udf` instead? Would it be faster enough?
- Are there some optimizations I can apply like cache the holidays table somehow on every worker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_facts = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('data1', '2022-05-08', '2022-05-14'),
     ('data1', '2022-05-08', '2022-05-21')],
    ['data', 'start_date', 'end_date']
)
df_holidays = spark.createDataFrame([('2022-05-10',)], ['holiday_date'])

df = df_facts.withColumn('exploded', F.explode(F.sequence(F.to_date('start_date'), F.to_date('end_date'))))
df = df.filter(~F.dayofweek('exploded').isin([1, 7]))
df = df.join(F.broadcast(df_holidays), df.exploded == df_holidays.holiday_date, 'anti')
df = df.groupBy('data', 'start_date', 'end_date').agg(F.count('exploded').alias('business_days'))

df.show()
# +-----+----------+----------+-------------+
# | data|start_date|  end_date|business_days|
# +-----+----------+----------+-------------+
# |data1|2022-05-08|2022-05-14|            4|
# |data1|2022-05-08|2022-05-21|            9|
# +-----+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Answers:

> Is there a better way than creating a UDF...?

This method does not use `udf`, so it must perform better.

> Is there a way to write a `pandas_udf` instead? Would it be faster enough?

`pandas_udf` performs better than regular `udf`. But no-udf approaches should be even better.

> Are there some optimizations I can apply like cache the holidays table somehow on every worker?

Spark engine performs optimizations itself. However, there are some relatively rare cases when you may help it. In the answer, I have used `F.broadcast(df_holidays)`. The `broadcast` sends the dataframe to all of the workers. But I am sure that the table would automatically be broadcasted to the workers, as it looks like it's supposed to be very small.

Comment: Looks promising, I wonder if I'll have any memory problems with explode. My data is in 71 columns. Will try and update.