How to get records whose due date is within next 5 business days from start and end date in SQL
I want to write a query which will return records where the due date ( will be calculated from start and end date ) is within next 5 business dayes ( exclude weekends)
I tried the following but this is not considering business days:
`SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (CURRENT_DATE - end_date) <= INTERVAL '5 days' `


Which SQL database are you using? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252519/count-work-days-between-two-dates.

I am using postgres ( PGadmin)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207701/count-business-days-between-2-dates-in-postgresql

The core problem is to advance/move by a certain number of business days. There are answers that address this.

For your case (5 work days) simple query
SELECT *
FROM test 
WHERE end_date<=(CURRENT_DATE 
             +4+case when extract(isodow from CURRENT_DATE)>1 then 2 else 0 end)

For monday(isodow=1) direct add 4 days - friday is due date.
Else additional 2 days (weekend) add to current date.
Other, longer, weekends don't matter.
